# Loop through Collection in VB ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following Razor script to loop through but it gives me the following error:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articles)
{
    <div>@item.Title</div>
}
```

Error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'foreach' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Source Error:

> Line 29:     Articles Line 30:  Line 31:     @foreach
>   (var item in ViewBag.Articles) Line 32:     { Line 33:
>
> @(item.index). @item.model.Description
>
> Source File: C:\Users\darchual\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Blog\Blog\Views\Blog\Details.vbhtml    Line: 31

It also says in my IDE that "'foreach' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

How do I loop through the collection?  Thank you for your help.

Edit:

Here is the whole code:

> @ModelType Blog.Blog
>
> @Code
>       ViewData("Title") = ViewBag.Title End Code
>
> ### Details
>
> Blog
>
> ```
> <div class="display-label">name</div>
> <div class="display-field">
>     @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.name)
> </div>
>
> <div class="display-label">description</div>
> <div class="display-field">
>     @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.description)
> </div>
>
> <div class="display-label">dateCreated</div>
> <div class="display-field">
>     @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.dateCreated)
> </div> </fieldset>
> ```
>
> Articles
>
> ```
> @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articles)
> {
>     <div>@item.Title</div>
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = Model.BlogId}) |
> @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") </p>
> ```

Here is the Blog object:

> Imports System.Data.Entity Imports
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
>
> Public Class Blog
>
> ```
> Public Property BlogId() As Integer
>
> Public Property Name() As String
> Public Property Description() As String
> Public Property DateCreated As Date
>
> Public Overridable Property Articles() As ICollection(Of Article)
> ```
>
> End Class
>
> Public Class BlogDbContext
>
> ```
> Inherits DbContext
> Public Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)
> ```
>
> End Class

Edit:

Finally got it to work.  Working code is:

```
@For Each item In ViewBag.Articles
    @<div>@item.Title</div>
Next
```

Comment: Omg, let me get this right, your mistake was using the wrong programming language? Holly shivers that is a classic! I'm going to remember that one L-O-L :)

Comment: Lol it was a simple mistake to make :)

Comment: One of the Top 10 signs that you are using too many different types of programming languages in any 24 hour period. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

```
@For Each item In ViewBag.Articles
    @<div>@item.Title</div>
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your page code is in VB.Net and `foreach()` is a C# construct.  You just need to modify your code use the VB Construct of the For Each loop:

[This thread on the ASP.NET Forum's has a good answer / code snippet](http://forums.asp.net/t/1769748.aspx/1):

```vb
Dim list As New List(Of Article)
list = ViewBag.Articles
If (list.Any()) 
Then     
    For Each item As Article In ViewBag.Articles 
        <div>@item.Title</div>
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I am trying to use foreach() in the context of Razor.  Can I not do this?  How can I loop through these records in my .vbhtml page?  I would like to use Razor here as that is the convention (I'm using MVC+Razor).

Comment: I have tried your new code but it says, "Item is not defined."  Thank you.

Comment: You may have to ad a using statement to you html page...i.e.  @using Blog.   I'm not sure what your Object model looks like

Comment: I tried adding using but it won't work.  I added my Blog object to the question.

Comment: If Item is undefined, are you sure there are objects in ViewBag.Articles?  Is "Item is not defined."  a compile or runtime error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already in a razor code block, you do not need the `@`

```
@if(ViewBag.Articles.Count>0)
{
   foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articles)
   { 
     <div>@item.Title</div>
   }
}
```

Are you using the **VB.NET version** of `foreach` ?

```
@For Each item As Article In ViewBag.Articles
  <div>@item.Title</div>
Next
```

Comment: Note: Using `Count` is not efficient because the code has to loop through every record. If you use `.Any()` the code can loop through one record and short circuit after the first as all you are trying to determine is if there is at least one. (No need to loop through 100k records for example just to determine if there is at least one).

Comment: I am not in a code block.  It keeps telling me that "foreach is not defined!"  I updated the question with my whole code.

Comment: Are you using the VB.NET version of foreach ? see my updated answer

Comment: I am using VB ASP.NET MVC.  The code I provided is in Views/Blogs/Details.vbhtml.  I can't apply the VB code you provided because this is a .vbhtml page.  So, I am trying to use Razor but it's  telling me foreach doesn't exist!

Comment: Are you saying you can not apply the Vb.NET version in provided because you are using VB  ? Doesn't make sense to me !

Comment: No, this is rendered using Razor as far as I know.  I don't know how to write VB code in a vbhtml document.  I'm trying to get the razor syntax to work.

Comment: I see now what you guys are telling me.  I have tried your VB/ Razor code but it says, "Type 'Article' is not defined."

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way the model binder works in ASP.NET MVC, there are a lot of scenarios where it's helpful to postback the index of each value in a list.

So I prefer to use an **indexed for loop** (over the simplicity of a strongly typed **for each loop**):

```html
@For i = 0 To Model.Articles.Count - 1
    Dim curItem = Model.Articles(i)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) curItem)
Next
```

**Further Reading**:
[Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-vb#looping-code) | [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#looping-code)